# Downloaded file with Play Framework has wrong filename

Tags: java, playframework, download, filenames, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework 2.0.2 to create an application that modifies Excel files uploaded by the user. Once the Excel file is uploaded and modified (server-side), the file is automatically downloaded by the user's browser.

However, using this code:

```
public static Result upload() throws IOException {
    Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart filePart = body.getFile("uploadedFile");

    modifyExcelFile(filepart.getFile()); // this method modifies the uploaded Excel file, and copies it to a file named "copy.xlsx"

    return ok(new File("copy.xlsx"));
}
```

the file that is downloaded by the client will be named after the current Controller. For example, if my Controller is named `UploadController`, the downloaded file is surprisingly named `uploadcontroller.xlsx`.

Any idea on how I could modify my code in order to have a tighter control on the downloaded file's name? I would like the downloaded file to be named `copy.xlsx`, not `uploadcontroller.xlsx`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this in the response header:

```
response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FILENAME");
```

Where FILENAME is the name you want your file to have.